# Assignments subclass to class and vice versa

Tags: java, arrays, inheritance, variable-assignment

I have this exercise:

```
public class TestClass{    
    public static void main(String args[]){       
        A[] a, a1;       
        B[] b;       
        a = new A[10]; 
        a1  = a;       
        b =  new B[20];       
        a = b;  // 1       
        b = (B[]) a;  // 2       
        b = (B[]) a1; // 3    
    } 
} 

class A { } 
class B extends A { }
```

In my opinion when I write: a=b I am assigning to object in b another reference (a). In practice, the object in b has two references (a and b).
But, for the rule of inheritance, the subclass is also of the superclass type, but the superclass is not also of the subclass type.

How can a superclass reference (a) be assigned to a subclass type (b)?
And this also applies to subsequent assignment.

In my opinion, if I wrote: b=a the code would compile without problems, but for the assignment a=b, there should be a compilation error.

Why is this assignment correct?

Comment: You're not new -- why are you not formatting your posted code correctly?

Comment: Formatted for you

Comment: `"In practice, the object in b has two references (a and b)"` -- no, that's one reference held by two variables

Comment: `b = (B[]) a1; // 3` this will fail. It will compile but will throw an exception since you're trying to cast an A array into a B array.

Comment: `"How can a superclass reference (a) be assigned to a subclass type (b)?"` -- this is not happening except on the failing line of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose Class A is instead Class Animal, and Class B is Class Dog.
You can create an animal that is a dog (a = b), because dogs are animals (subclass). But this does not work the other way around (b = a), because an animal can be more than a dog such as a cat, so you cannot assign a cat to be a dog. So to do this, you'd have to explicitly cast the Animal to be a Dog (b = (Dog) a).

Comment: look this example: 
       Object []oo=new Object[1];
              String []ss = new String [3];
       oo=ss; //ok because String is also object. 
       ss=oo; //compilation error because Object isn't String

Comment: ss = oo will give you a compilation error, because oo could be a non-String object. So if you cast it: ss = (String []) oo, it will compile fine.